# Why is random.shuffle so much slower than using sorted function?

Tags: python, performance, random, shuffle

When using pythons `random.shuffle` function, I noticed it went significantly faster to use `sorted(l, key=lambda _: random.random())` than `random.shuffle(l)`. As far as I understand, both ways produce completely random lists, so why does `shuffle` take so much longer?

Below are the times using `timeit` module.

```
from timeit import timeit
setup = 'import random\nl = list(range(1000))'

# 5.542 seconds
print(timeit('random.shuffle(l)', setup=setup, number=10000))

# 1.878 seconds
print(timeit('sorted(l, key=lambda _: random.random())', setup=setup, number=10000))
```

Comment: Ideally, the shuffle function implements [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Comparison_with_other_shuffling_algorithms), which has O(_n_) runtime complexity, whereas general sorting has O(_n_ log _n_) runtime complexity. I suspect `sorted(l, key=lambda _: random.random())` isn’t the right way to shuffle arrays: see the mentioned link.

Comment: @user4642212: Python's is a Fisher-Yates (assuming I'm reading Wikipedia and the `random.shuffle` source code correctly). The link does mention that the `sorted` with `random.random()` would be correct *if* the sorting algorithm itself broke ties randomly (which Python does not; it's a stable sort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On CPython (the reference interpreter) `random.shuffle` is implemented in Python (and implemented in terms of `_randbelow`, itself a Python wrapper around `getrandbits`, the C level function that ultimately implements it, and which can end up being called nearly twice as often as strictly necessary in an effort to ensure the outputs are unbiased); `sorted` (and `random.random`) are implemented in C. The overhead of performing work in Python is higher than performing similar work in C.

Comment: Why doesn't `random.shuffle` just return the list using `sorted` if it runs so much faster using C?

Comment: @Evan: It's using a fairly painstaking algorithm that guarantees (to the limits of the PRNG) a perfect shuffle; avoiding bias is a surprisingly hard problem, and making it faster is less of a priority than making sure it's definitely correct. There have been a number of bugs in the `random` module that led to slight biases in output (it's why `_randbelow` is implemented the way it is now), and they've generally been pretty gunshy about using faster algorithms that aren't provably unbiased.